# array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, laravel, argv

I am using my application in a shared hosting, it is produced in laravel. It gives me

> PHP Warning:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in line 53
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in line 49

with this code:

```
class ArgvInput extends Input
{
    private $tokens;
    private $parsed;

    public function __construct(array $argv = null, InputDefinition $definition = null)
    {
        if (null === $argv) {
            $argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
        }

        // strip the application name
        array_shift($argv);

        $this->tokens = $argv;

        parent::__construct($definition);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code which creates the `ArgvInput` object.

Comment: on this line `array_shift($argv);` `$argv` is null, it should be an **array**, you can do like that `if(is_array($argv)) { array_shift($argv);  }`

Comment: i think that you don't have a key on 'argv' in  $_SERVER['argv'];

Comment: Try printing the value of `$argv` just after the `if` statement. It'll help you determine the value of `$argv`. And will also clear the speculation of not having any key on 'argv' in `$_SERVER['argv']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can mean that the `$_SERVER['argv']` variable is also empty. I'd recommend to check it first, or you can do this:

```
$argv = $argv ?? $_SERVER['argv'] ?? [];
```

This way you'll always have an array, even if there's no input, in which case the array will be empty, and it won't trigger that error